# ldap3 connection returns wrong code after bind

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldap3

I encountered following issue while working with LDAP3 package: When I am passing wrong credentials (wrong username and wrong password), I am getting same Microsoft Active Directory LDAP Result Codes sub-codes for Bind Response, as when only password is invalid.

My code:

```
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, NONE, NTLM

server = Server(url, use_ssl=True, get_info=NONE)
con = Connection(server, user='ValidID', password='ValidPassword')
con.bind()
con.unbind()
print(con.result)
```

Result I am getting here:

> {'result': 0, 'description': 'success', 'dn': '', 'message': '',
>   'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}

Nothing wrong with that. But...

```
con = Connection(server, user='InvalidID', password='InvalidPassword')
con.bind()
con.unbind()
print(con.result)
```

Gives me following result:

> {'result': 49, 'description': 'invalidCredentials', 'dn': '',
>   'message': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment:
>   AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580\x00', 'referrals': None,
>   'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}

According to ldap wiki:

> 52e - ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE
>
> Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.    Will prevent most other er from being displayed as noted.

In that case I shouldn't be getting "data 52e" message, because username is not valid.

Or I am getting something wrong?
Another thing coming to my head, it might be the ldap server fault, and it is sending wrong messages

Answer (score 1):

That happens, because you should bind port **after initialization** of server connection and unbind **after manipulations**
Should look like this example

```
ldap_server = ldap3.Server(SERVER, get_info=ldap3.ALL)
    conn = ldap3.Connection(
        server=ldap_server,
        user='user_principal_name',
        password='password'
    )
    conn.bind()
    ldap3.extend.microsoft.modifyPassword.ad_modify_password(
        conn,
        'user_distinguished_name',
        new_secret,
        old_secret,
        controls=None
    )
    conn.unbind()
```

Comment: autobind dosen't unbind, to my sorry

Comment: That's an old question, but in my case I didn't do any manipulations, just got wrong error code when trying to connect with invalid credentials. Looking at it after some time, probably server was misconfigured, and didn't handle it properly